# How to manually transfer Firefox settings to the snap version?

Tags: firefox, snap, configuration, transfer

I make use of Firefox sync but only for bookmarks, call me old fashioned but I choose not to send all my passwords for storage elsewhere.

Each time I start using a new computer, I transfer the directory:

~/.mozilla/firefox/whatever.default

to the new computer and make sure Firefox picks up its configuration from the files in that xxxxx.default directory. This has worked perfectly well for many years and many new machines.

I have just installed Ubuntu 21.10 on a new disk and Firefox is the Snap version.

Expecting to transfer the xxxxxxxx.default directory to:
~/.mozilla/firefox
I am thwarted by the fact that the Snap version of Firefox hasn't created and thus doesn't appear to use ~/.mozilla

Does anybody know how to transfer Firefox configuration from one machine to another without using Firefox Sync ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply searched the disk for a file or directory named "firefox" and I now know that what was previously:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox
```

becomes

```
~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox
```

Thus I did what I normally do and I'm now using Firefox from the new disk and all is well.

2023-04-23 Later edit

Going through this process again with Firefox version 112 I became aware of a potential difficulty if the Firefox version has moved on since the config files were written. Best try and get config files that were written by the version you are going to use.

Comment: Just wanted to add, after my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade, on first run of the new snap-based firefox install, I caught the snap simply using "cp -R" to copy .mozilla/firefox into the snap location (... and I suppose .mozilla/extensions too since it's there.)  So this'll definitely work without repurcussions, since it's what the stock "apt-based to snap-based" migration is doing anyway.